# Angular5 call function inside ngFor Loop

Tags: angular

I need to change each date {{gallery.created }} under *ngFor loop to new Date(gallery.created). I meant I need to call new Date(timestamp)
 under *ngFor loop. But its not working, I am able to get the values in console but HTMl is not rendering it

```
 <div *ngFor="let gallery of galleries; trackBy: trackHero">

          <p> Published on {{this.dateValue| surveysDate:'date':'short'}}</p>
        </div>
```

Ts

```
public trackHero(index, gallery) {
    this.dateValue = new Date(gallery.created);
    console.log(this.dateValue);
}
```

The other way which I tried is below with same HTML format. But its population all the dates for each element

```
this.someService.search(query).then((response: any) => {
      if (response) {
        this.galleries = response.results;
        this.dateValue =  this.galleries.map((x: any) => new Date(x.created));


      }
});
```

Comment: That is not what you use a trackBy function for. It's used to return the trackable reference for when the DOM should be updated.

Comment: Is there any other way to solve my issue? new Date(gallery.created) and render it on HTML. gallery.created is coming from ngFor Loop

Comment: It would be better to assign the new dates before showing the data in the view.

Comment: @ConnorsFan, I am doing in same way but getting error. Do you have some example or stackblitz for that?

Comment: Show us how you populate `galleries` (with the context, for example in which lifecycle hook).

Comment: @ConnorsFan updated

Comment: By the way, why don't you just display: `{{ gallery.created | surveysDate:'date':'short' }}`? You need the `dateValue` array for something else?

Comment: @ConnorsFan  I need to apply new Date(timestamp) for each gallery.created. 
{{gallery.created}} gives me 1305175330000 then this should be like {{new Date(1305175330000 )| custom date pipes.}}

Doing same its not recognizing the Date. in HTML

Comment: Would `{{ gallery.created | date | surveysDate:'date':'short' }}` work for you?

Comment: @ConnorsFan no..

Comment: @ConnorsFan can I fix using map?

Comment: If you really want to display the `dataValue` array, synchronized with `galleries`, you can use the loop index: `<div *ngFor="let gallery of galleries; let i = index">` and `{{this.dateValue[i] | surveysDate:'date':'short'}}`. Assuming that `dateValue` has been populated in code as shown in the question.

Comment: @ConnorsFan using trackHero way?

Comment: No, with `this.dataValue = this.galleries.map(...)`.

Comment: Is it the best way to do it? I was thinking to change whole thing into subscription and observables but I was looking some sample code for that too

Comment: Another method: in code `getCreatedDate(gallery) { return new Date(gallery.created); }`; in template: `{{ getCreatedDate(gallery) | surveysDate:'date':'short' }}`.